# How to kill weeds (see picture) without killing tall fescue grass

Tags: grass, weed-control, fescue

Does anyone know what the weeds are called below? In addition, does anyone know how to remove them without killing the tall fescue grass?
There is a lot of land so picking the weeds is not a realistic option.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have ground ivy: https://turf.purdue.edu/ground-ivy/

Comment: I don't know if it's ground ivy - the leaves look too rounded. Maybe another species in the genus? I do see some chickweed, though. Are you looking for an organic or chemical solution? Where in the world are you located?

Comment: Near atlanta. Any solution as long as its affordable.

Answer (score 1):

You need a selective turf weedkiller. Pop along to a decent garden centre and see what they have available. Follow the instructions to the letter.

Answer (score 0):

How much land is it, you cant remove the ivy by hand? Because the plant is *stoloniferous* (produces Root runners) it will continue to spread from its roots or bits of stem which reroot, even small infestations can withstand repeated hand weedings. The best strategy is to dig up it's comprehensive root ball and destroy it. It's the only way for permanent removal.